# Why can IConfiguration be injected into singleton and transient services but not in scoped?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a `dotnet new console` application based on [Cocona](https://github.com/mayuki/Cocona) that I set up the following way:

```bash
mkdir CoconaBug
cd CoconaBug

dotnet new console
dotnet add package Cocona

touch appsettings.json
touch appsettings.Development.json
```

The source code for a minimal project illustrating the problem is this:

```
using Cocona;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = Cocona.CoconaApp.CreateBuilder();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.AddCommand("do-something", (
    IScopedService service) =>
{
    service.DoSomething();
});

app.Run();


internal interface IScopedService
{
    void DoSomething();
}

internal class ScopedService : IScopedService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public ScopedService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_config["Test"]);
    }
}
```

I want to make use of appsettings.$ENVIRONMENT.json, so after creating these files I inject `IConfiguration`.

appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Test": "TestTestTest.Plain"
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```json
{
  "Test": "TestTestTest.Development"
}
```

If the application is launched as follows, an Exception is thrown if the service is registered as *scoped*.

```bash
$ DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Development" dotnet run do-something

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'IScopedService' from root provider.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.OnResolve(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Cocona.Command.Binder.CoconaParameterBinder.Bind(CommandDescriptor commandDescriptor, IReadOnlyList`1 commandOptionValues, IReadOnlyList`1 commandArgumentValues)
   at Cocona.Command.Dispatcher.Middlewares.CoconaCommandInvokeMiddleware.DispatchAsync(CommandDispatchContext ctx)
   at Cocona.Command.Dispatcher.Middlewares.HandleParameterBindExceptionMiddleware.DispatchAsync(CommandDispatchContext ctx)
   at Cocona.Command.Dispatcher.Middlewares.HandleExceptionAndExitMiddleware.DispatchAsync(CommandDispatchContext ctx)
```

If however the service is registered as either *transient* or *singleton*, it can be resolved and displays **TestTestTest.Development** as expected

Comment: You need to create a service scope before you can resolve scoped services.

Comment: but why does it work when just launch `dotnet run do-something` without setting DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT to Development. In that case scoped services can be injected without me having to create a scope myself

Comment: Because validating scopes is optional https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6085dc2c1c1b678a6512565d351f926bfbdaf4a3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceProvider.cs#L62 with defaults based on build type or environment name.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That link was so helpful. After digging through it, I figured out that I can use any environment except Development. I am still looking for a way to disable `ServiceProviderOptions.ValidateScopes` for Development.

Comment: The default is documented; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovideroptions.validatescopes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 (impl. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6085dc2c1c1b678a6512565d351f926bfbdaf4a3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L319) avoiding those defaults is less obvious https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/aspnet-core-dependency-injection-what-is-the-iserviceprovider-and-how-is-it-built.